# why it is not possible to have array of void?

Tags: c, arrays, void

I am going through geeksforgeeks and found that we cant have array of void and functions. As I think array of function not allowed because of variable size of function (correct me if i wrong).

Comment: You *can* have an array of function (pointers).

Comment: What is an "array of void and functions"? Maybe an array of pointers to functions which have an empty parameter list and return type `void`?

Comment: Meanings of  "*void*": https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/void

Comment: void means data type void. like we can have array of void pointers .

Comment: What would you want to store in a `void` typed thingy?

Comment: https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/can-we-have-an-array-of-all-types-in-c/ refer this link

Comment: The 2nd statement on the page you linked  "In C there were no arrays for functions" is more or less wrong.

Comment: @alk It's correct. You can have an array of function pointers but not an array of functions.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Functions have no size at all; functions aren't data. You can't have a single "variable of function" either. That's why you can't have an array of functions.

Similarly, you can't have an array of void because you can't have a single element of type void:

```
void x;  // what would this do?
```

(Formally this is an error because `void` is an incomplete type (and it can't be made complete).)

`void` has several distinct uses (all of which fall under the general umbrella of "not a real type"):

- As a return type: `void foo(...);`

  This indicates that the function does not return a value at all.
- As the sole element of a parameter list: `T foo(void);`

  This indicates that the function takes no arguments. Logically you'd expect the syntax for this to be `T foo();` (an empty parameter list), but that already had a different meaning in pre-standard C, which did not have function prototypes. `T foo(void)` is a bit of a syntactic hack. Again, `void` marks the absence of a value.

  (C++ simplified things. In C++ `T foo();` means the same thing as `T foo(void);`: `foo` takes no arguments.)
- As a generic pointer type: `void *ptr;`

  This means `ptr` is a pointer to some kind of data, but we don't know what it is. This is a special case in the rules of the language. It's different from other pointer types because

  - we can't use it directly (dereferencing the pointer (as in `*ptr`) is an error because you can't have a value of type `void`)
  - we can implicitly convert other (data) pointer types to `void *`:

    ```
    int i = 42;
    void *ptr;
    ptr = &i;   // 'int *' -> 'void *'
    ```
  - we can implicitly convert `void *` to other (data) pointer types:

    ```
    void *ptr = ...;
    int *pi;
    pi = ptr;  // 'void *' -> 'int *'
    ```

  Because of this, `void *` is used as a general "pointer to value of unknown type".

Answer (score 0):

You can't have a variable of type `void` (or an array of `void`) for the simple reason that there are no values of type `void` for it to hold.

If you wrote

```
void v;
```

and then

```
v = ???
```

there's not a single thing you could replace the `???` with that would make any sense at all.

Comment: A naive person would argue that `void f(int); void v = f(42);` or even `void v = (void)42;` would make perfect sense, given that `f(42)` and `(void)42` are already valid expressions of type `void`.

Comment: Well, you're right.  I thought of that, too, but decided not to mention it, as it was inconvenient to my assertion that there's "not a single thing". :-\